# Is it "consumer savings" or "consumers’ savings"?

Tags: grammar, possessives

> In the previous year, consumers' savings had decreased.

or

> In the previous year, consumer savings had decreased.

Which one is valid and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say either, depending on the context. The term **consumer savings** is used by economists to describe broad trends in the behavior of a population. But you could use **consumers' savings** to refer to a specific set of consumers apart from the general populace.

Comment: You can *say* either, because they sound much the same anyway. But I personally don't think I've ever seen the apostrophe'd form. And even though it's grammatically defensible, I think I'd just classify it as a *grocers' apostrophe* (I don't have any preference between *grocers'* and *grocer's* though!)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Agreed. Still, it *is* possible to construct a legitimate English sentence using the apostrophe, so I opted to include it.

Comment: Well I'm certainly not going to get in a sparring match with *you* over what constitutes a valid utterance! I'm just indicating my preference for the uninflected form in the vast majority of contexts. A preference which I think you share, but didn't particularly call attention to in your answer.

Comment: @Fumblefingers: What part of "Agreed" made you think I was looking for a sparring match?

Comment: Nothing at all! That's I italicised *you*! My apologies if it came across as a 'back-handed' compliment.

Answer (score 1):

Curiously, I hit exactly the same question with one of my children. We were in a hotel eating breakfast. He asked why this was called a *hotel restaurant*, rather than *hotel's restaurant*. It is a grammatical feature called **apposition**.

Comment: So, what's the answer? Apostrophe-s or not?

Comment: No apostrophe, @Jimi Oke.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the word 'consumer' (no apostrophe) acts as a qualifier to the word 'savings'.

So, we begin with the head word 'savings' and explain what savings we are taking about by using the word 'consumer'.

'Consumer' then, performs much the same job as the determiner 'those'. We could say

*those savings*

and the grammatical structure would be quite the same.

Therefore, while you could say 'consumer's savings', the term you are after here is **consumer savings**.

N.B.: Generally, 'consumer's savings' would be preceded by the article 'the', as *The Consumers* in this sense would be a specific group of people, outlined elsewhere in its context.